# MongoDb : count documents in other collection without a join operation

Tags: mongodb, join

I have 2 collections :

guilds:

```
{
  name: { type: String },
  owner: { type: String },
  discord: {
    id: { type: String }
  }
}
```

logCommands:

```
{
  discordId: { type: String },
  guild: { type: String },
  name: { type: String },
}
```

I have writed a function to get all guilds of a owner and count for each guild the sum of logs related to the guild.

The function:

```
Guild.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        owner: ObjectId(userId),
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'logcommands',
        localField: 'discord.id',
        foreignField: 'guild',
        as: 'logs',
      },
    },
    { $addFields: { commandCount: { $size: '$logs' } } },
  ]);
```

This is works but I don't want that mongoDB retrieves all logCommands concerned (for increase performance), I just want the count of logs for each guild, it is possible to get that without performs a join operation ($lookup) ?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: If you only need the count for each guild, you may do a `$group` in the `logCommands`, like `{$group: {_id: "$guild", commandCount: {$sum: 1}}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- you can use lookup with pipeline, and the lookup result to have only the count number
- the bellow needs MongoDB 5, with localfield and foreignfield to be the same with your lookup, except the small pipeline just to count
- after lookup, `$set` is  to change structure a bit.

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70421578-m)

```js
Guild.aggregate(
[{"$match":{"owner":1}},
 {"$lookup":
  {"from":"logcommands",
   "localField":"discord.id",
   "foreignField":"guild",
   "pipeline":[{"$count":"count"}],
   "as":"logs"}},
 {"$set":{"logs":{"$arrayElemAt":["$logs.count", 0]}}}])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Do you know if your aggregation is more faster than mine ? I'am struggling to get the execution  time for an aggregation

Comment: works like yours just dont construct big array with documents, to make it faster you can create an index on the foreignFiled `guild`

Comment: on owner also make index ,and it will be super fast